# Recalling software keyboard only in English [without the option of choosing other languages]?

Tags: android

How can I have the android keyboard just in English [without the option of choosing the other languages] when recall it to fill a box (For example `EditText`)? I want to do this by programming not by changing the android setting.

Comment: Why not just disallow non-english characters? It seems like you want a workaround for something that should be system-controlled.

Comment: You do not have that degree of control over the input method editors. The user can choose whichever input method editor they want, with whatever language support is offered by that input method editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Below code :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nameText"
    android:layout_width="177dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" />
```

Or :

```
EditText state = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtState);


                Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
                Matcher ms = ps.matcher(state.getText().toString());
                boolean bs = ms.matches();
                if (bs == false) {
                    if (ErrorMessage.contains("invalid"))
                        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + "state,";
                    else
                        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + "invalid state,";

                }
```